# How to update 2 rows value with sum of previous values and with new value using Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to update 2 rows values using Mysql query  but  sum of previous value  and add with new value but problem is that the query which return is throwing error  so how to do this?

[image]

```
10 //assume I want to update with value 10
```

for example  balance column  should get updated with sum of previous value and new values like 68+10=78 and 70+10=80 based on sessid ,but query which I have return is not working.

```
UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = 10+(balance) WHERE sessid  IN(11,3);
```

Comment: *which return is throwing error* It will be helpful if you post the error message. Also ther is no "previous" value in a database.

Comment: Why does 68+ 10 = 70?

Comment: @P.Salmon by mistake i typed 0 instead of 8

Answer (score 4):

Finally i solved my issue actually query should be like this

```
UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = balance+10 WHERE sessid  IN(11,3);
```

Comment: The end result for this and the original query is exactly the same so why the upvotes?